# hiveconf variable in where

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a query

```
set short_string = "'M', 'C'";

select *
from db.table
where code not in (${hiveconf:short_string})
```

I want it to return records that do not have 'M', 'C' in code, but this doesn't work and returns all records. If I write 'M', 'C' dirrectly everything is fine. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
set foo= ('This','That');

select * from <table> where <column> not in ${hiveconf:foo};
```

The point being you don't need to surround the entire variable with quotes, it's a direct substitution.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
set short_string='M', 'C';
```

instead of

```
set short_string = "'M', 'C'";
```

you don't need to use double quotes in the hive variables, everything after the equal will be part of the variable.